# CSS ignores width of children when using aspect ratio

Tags: css, aspect-ratio

I have encountered an issue regarding CSS's `aspect-ratio` on child elements.

I've been trying to style an element's width and height (both the same) to be equal to the height of the parent container. Using `height: 100%;` and `aspect-ratio: 1;` makes this work, however;

It seems the parent container ignores the children's resized width when using `aspect-ratio`, meaning the parent container ends up with the wrong width.

I've included a codepen illustrating the issue. Notice how the width does increase with each new element, but the width increase does not correspond to the actual width of the added elements.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 8px;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  column-gap: 16px;
  
  width: fit-content;
}
.button_container {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 8px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: fit-content;
}
.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  border: 1px solid black;
}
.first_case {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
.second_case {
  height: 100%;
  width: 56px;
}
```

```html
<p>Fixed width (this is how it should look)</p>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Text<br/>More text<br/>Lots of text
  </div>
  <div class="button_container">
    <div class="button second_case">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="button second_case">
      B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Aspect ratio</p>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Text<br/>More text<br/>Lots of text
  </div>
  <div class="button_container">
    <div class="button first_case">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="button first_case">
      B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/th3o4or/pen/ZEoqMrm

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: @Maurice, I have not figured it out yet, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "display:flex;" for containers and set some try some different with and height values.
its solved:
https://codepen.io/sawacrow/pen/eYPYjwr

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 8px;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  column-gap: 16px;
}
.button_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;      width: -webkit-fill-available;
  column-gap: 8px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  border: 1px solid black;
}
.first_case {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
.second_case {
  height: 100%;
  width: 56px;
}
```

```html
<p>Fixed width (this is how it should look)</p>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Text<br/>More text<br/>Lots of text
  </div>
  <div class="button_container">
    <div class="button second_case">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="button second_case">
      B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Aspect ratio</p>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Text<br/>More text<br/>Lots of text
  </div>
  <div class="button_container">
    <div class="button first_case">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="button first_case">
      B
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```